# How can I "Go to Declaration" using VIM without going through a long list?

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin

I'm reading a huge cpp project with hundreds of .cpp and .h files, and I want to do it more efficiently by using the "Go to Declaration" function.

I tried vim + ctags + cscope, but when I "Go to Declaration" by using "Ctrl + ]", it came up a LONG LONG list of "declaration" for me to select.

For example, I want to find the declaration of "class Foo::reset()", but it comes to me lots of candidates such as "class Bar::reset()" or "Class Blahblah::reset()".

I wonder if there is a fascinating way to find the REAL DECLARATION of a function, but not to choose the right one for a long list manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither Vim, nor ctags nor cscope have the ability to understand your code and go to the declaration you want.

You might want to try Clang-based [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/doc/youcompleteme.txt#L769-L802) or [clang-complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/pull/316).

Comment: Ycm told me that I can use "Go To Definition" because of there's lost header file(s). But the function I want to see is not in that lost header file(s).  p.s. The "Go To Definition" in Eclipse is available even though the headers doesn't exist.

Comment: But YCM and clang-complete can only jump to a definition if it is in the scope of the current compilation unit, right? Is there any way to jump to a definition anywhere in the project?

Answer (score 1):

The YouCompleteMe plugin [supports that](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/README.md#the-gotodefinition-subcommand).

Answer (score 1):

It is a heavy-weight solution, but you could also install Eclipse with the C/C++ Developer tools, and use the Eclim plugin (eclim.org) to talk to Eclipse for searches and completion.

Comment: I'm now using Eclipse-cdt before I successfully configure my VIM. Eclipse is great. Nice answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both CLion and VSCode are much better than Eclipse, provide this functionality and have Vim plugins.